# validation.yml not working wit image file

Tags: symfony

i read [this documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Image.html) about this issue

but not working

and return this error:

> The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?

mi code is

in  **MyApp\MainBundle\Resources\config\validation.yml**

MyApp\MainBundle\Entity\Product:

```
properties:
    name: # YES VALIDATE
        - Length:
            min: 2
            max: 60
    image: # NOT VALIDATE 
        - Image:
            maxSize: 6000000
            mimeTypes: [image/*]
            mimeTypesMessage: Solo imagenes estan permitidas
```

the **Entity MyApp\MainBundle\Entity\Product**

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $image;


// UPLOAD OF IMAGES   

/**
 * Set image
 */
public function setImage(File $image= null)
{
    $this->image = $image;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get image
 *
 * @return UploadedFile 
 */
public function getImage()
{
    return $this->image;
}


// UPLOAD  IMAGES    
/**
* @ORM\PrePersist()
*/
public function prePersist()
{        
    ## .....
}

/**
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function preUpdate()
{ 
    ## .....
}

## ETC .....
```

Answer (score 2):

The error that you are receiving has nothing to do with your validation.  The problem is in your controller.  You must return some kind of `Response` object in your controller.  Take a look at the controller you are using for your product entity, and ensure that you are returning a `Response` object in each Action.  It looks like you aren't returning anything